# Disassemble IAR 8051 with debug information

Tags: iar, 8051

I am developing 8051 firmware in a project and have to use IAR as the toolchain. The build system is CMake. I cannot use the IAR IDE.

In order to optimize my source code I want to look at the disassembly of the resulting binary, preferably with labels. Is there any way to make xlink output something that I can analyse? I know that the IAR IDE debugger has a debug view, but I cannot use the IDE. It seems xlink can output a lot of file formats, but which ones allow to extract debug information on command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is commonly not the tool to produce assembly listings. It generally only knows of bytes, sections, references to be resolved, addresses to be located, output formats to generate, and so on. Only few linkers know how to patch compiler/assembler generated listings with the final addresses.

So you would need to look at the tool that knows about machine code, the compiler or the assembler. Unfortunately IAR does not seem to provide a disassembler.

A quick web research on "iar 8051 compiler option" revealed [this compiler guide](https://wwwfiles.iar.com/8051/webic/doc/EW8051_CompilerGuide.pdf). And another quick look in the table of contents led to the chapter "Descriptions of compiler options", which describes among others the option `-l`. The guide says:

> Use this option to generate an assembler or C/C++ listing to a file. Note that this option can be used one or more times on the command line.

This should be enough to see the generated assembly. If you want the allocated addresses after linking, the linker can provide that.

Anyway, as a last resort you would like to check out decent disassemblers like [Ghidra](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/releases).

Comment: Thank you that you condescend to reply. I was explicitly asking about the output of xlink. The listing files generated by xlink do not contain assembly information, neither seems IAR to provide any tools to extract something from UBROF files.

Yes, icc8051 can generate listing files containing the original sources + generated assembly, but only for one translation unit. But yes, it's much better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for reworking your reply. I was so used to the ELF format and its merits that I totally forgot that everything is complicated and difficult in the proprietary world.

Comment: Hmm, if you say ELF, do you mean GCC and friends? I don't think that its linkers can generate a listing. However, objdump is _the_ tool to disassemble. ;-) And yes, such is missing in almost any other compiler system. We are quite fastidious. (Is this the right word? I'm not a native speaker.)

Comment: ELF is the default object/library/executable format on Linux, but is also the default of gcc on most targets these days. The swiss army knife is the binutils package where objdump is part of.

I do realize only now that objdump also just uses the symbol information from ELF files when disassembling, but no debug information. I also forgot that PE (Windows) keeps debug information in separate files. I was mixing everything a bit up. Thanks again for your hint of using the compiler to output the disassembly. I was so eager to extract it from the final binary or to let the linker somehow do it.